# Can O(1) or O(log n) be used for the count of elements and how would that work

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, sortedlist

I have a task that sounds like this:

*Let A be a sorted list with n elements. We would like to add some elements
into A so that the entire list is sorted as well.*

*(i) Give an O(n)-algorithm that adds O(1) elements into A and returns a sorted list.*

*(ii) Give an O(n)-algorithm that adds O(log n) elements into A and returns a sorted list.*

I understand how the big O notation could be used to describe time and space complexity (and in the task i assume both parts require time complexity to be O(n)) but in this task it seems to describe the amount of elements too.It is really difficult to understand. Could anyone explain how to interpret the "O(1)" the "O(log n)" part?

**EDIT:** Do you have any suggestions what type of algorithm should I use to complete the tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) you need to add O(1) elements into A, means that you are adding a constant element, meaning one element. So you could add that by first creating a linked list from the list of elements which would be O(n). Further adding a node by iterating over the linked list at the any position would be O(n). Hence the overall time complexity would be O(n).

For Reference:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-linked-list-which-is-sorted-how-will-you-insert-in-sorted-way/

(ii) We can first sort the O(log n) elements we want to insert, this can be done, by an algorithm like merge sort or heap sort, in O(log(n) log (log(n))). if log(n) = k, then that would be O(k log(k)). Next we can make a merge of the two lists (or any kind of datastructure, as long as we can iterate over it in ascending order). This merge can be done in O(k+n), since we concurrently can iterate over the two lists, and each time "emit" the smallest of the two and advance the corresponding cursor.

So the total time complexity would be O(n).

For example for two arrays that are sorted, we can merge these with:

```
public static int[] merge_sorted(int[] a, int[] b) {
    k = a.length;
    n = b.length;
    int[] c = new int[k+n];
    int ai = 0;
    int bi = 0;
    int ci = 0;
    while(ai < k && bi < n) {
        if(a[ai] <= b[bi]) {
            c[ci++] = a[ai++];
        } else {
            c[ci++] = b[bi++];
        }
    }
    while(ai < k) {
        c[ci++] = a[ai++];
    }
    while(bi < n) {
        c[ci++] = b[bi++];
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those describe the size of the set of values to add to the list relative to its current size N.